# Selecting an anchor tag based on an id with a patterned name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just trying to add a click function to all anchor tags whose ids are named by a specific pattern say 'some_ID1', 'some_ID2'etc. I referred the [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/) documentation but I'm not able to get it. Here's the sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjqxuhd4/4/)

```
<a href="#" id="some_id1"> some link 1 </a> <br>
<a href="#" id="some_id2"> some link 2 </a> <br>
<a href="#" id="some_id3"> some link 3 </a>
```

```js
console.log("link is " + $("#a[id|='some_']"));

$("#a[id|='some_']").on ('click', function (e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log ("a click " + $("#a[id|='some_']"));
});
```

Comment: `#a` matches `id="a"` exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use attribute starts with selector. you also need to remove id selector `#` from Element Selector `a`:

```
$('a[id^="some_id"]').on ('click', function (e){ 
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log ("a click " + this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case simply use `^`(starts with selector) and remove `#` from the selector as shown below :-

```
$("a[id^='some_id']").on('click', function (e){    
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log ("a click " + this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting ids starting width "some_":

```
$('a[id^="some_"]')
```

Selecting ids ending width "anid"

```
$('a[id$="some_"]')
```